# How to write this properly?

Tags: american-english, writing

> "If you ask someone why they rewarded someone else, they will tell you
>   that they deserve it."

I think that the intended meaning is pretty clear, but how do you say that properly without falling into a math-y kind of sentence like:

> If you ask person A why they rewarded person B, person A will tell
>   you that person B deserves it.

Having a hard time coming up with something that's not too ... heavy.

PS: non-native speaker here.

Comment: Hi ben, welcome to EL&U.  I've flagged this post as 'belongs on English Language  Learners'.  If you aren't a fluent speaker, post your questions on our beginner/novice site English Language Learners.  Follow the link and post your question there.  You can delete this post yourself, or wait for the moderators to do so.  https://ell.stackechange.com

Comment: Hi Lordilogy, thank you for your advice. Well I consider myself a fluent speaker. Does this question sound too trivial for this community?

Comment: But your postscript states: *non-english speaker here*, does it not?

Comment: Ah my bad, I meant non native English speaker!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I have retracted my flag.

Comment: The meaning is fairly clear, but to clarify that the 'theys' are different people you could say '...they will tell you that the person deserves it',

Comment: @Lordology What OP's comment shows you is that you had no reason to suggest ELL. This site does not preclude NNSs from asking questions.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, but before editing to put NNS, he accidentally misstated that English was not his native language.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just forego one of the pronouns:

> If you ask someone why they rewarded someone else, they will tell you that **the recipient** deserved it.